# Code cleanup data structure

Tags: structure

How to clean up/remove Verific data structures

```
int x = 15;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    mySequence[i] = 0;
}
mySequence[0] = -127;
delete[] mySequence;
```

Comment: I Don't fully understand the question.
Your code does not allocate dynamic memory(with new).
In that case, everything is allocated on the stack so you really don't need to free any memory at all...

Comment: clean up/remove Verific TO DATA STRUCTURE